# How does Spring connect to MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb

I am currently taking a look at Java Spring and i want to note that, regarding web services, I rather used JavaScript (NodeJS) or Python Django in the past.

To be honest, i find Spring a bit complicated or abstract compared to NodeJS with Express.
In NodeJS, I can connect to a MongoDB database within 1 line of code `mongoose.connect(....)` and thats it, nothing irritating or unclear to me. In Spring, i tried to find out how to connect to a MongoDB database and found **5 different approaches using 20 different classes** and still didnt figure out, what actually happens behind the scenes.

I've done their official little quickstart tutorial which uses a class implementing the `MongoRepository` interface and after doing that, when I run the application, the logs of Tomcat Server say that the application is 'magically' connected to MongoDB database. So I didnt even have to provide any connection details like the URI, which I always had to when I used NodeJS. So the process lacks any `connect()` code apparently.

So, my question is, can someone clearify what exactly happens behind the scenes and maybe why its so different to NodeJS?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make a POJO class, In @Document write your collection name, not your database name
In MongoDB, you can create easily create a collection name

To create a database
`use <your-database-name>`

To create a collection name `db.createCollection("Book")`

```
@Document(collection = "Book")
public class Customer {

@Id
public Integer id;
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
 cons, getter and setter
}
```

Now, in your `application.properties` file which is under your `resources` directory of your project

```
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.database=<your Database name>
```

and last you must have to add a dependency in you pom.xml file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem was rather focused on **where** in the code is Spring actually connecting to the database. I mean, in a NodeJS application, i can pretty much see where the connection part is happening by looking for a `.connect()` function or something similar inside the code, but in Spring i struggle to see it.

Comment: @Manu because of spring data in your pom.xml Spring tries to Connect on application Startup

Comment: @medTech so its abstracted away from the developer and the connection is happening automatically on application start instead, invoked by, say a function somewhere inside the source code of `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` ?

Comment: @Manu yes. Spring uses inversion of controle so it builds an application context on startup with beans. Their lifecycle is managed by spring.